# Translate code from Delphi to C ++ Builder 10.3

Tags: delphi, c++builder

There is a library for [parsing](https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe/blob/master/source/ALXmlDoc.pas).

I added `ALXmlDoc.pas` to the project, C++Builder created `ALXmlDoc.hpp` 
 
In `ALXmlDoc.pas` lines 177,178:

```pascal
property Nodes [const Name: AnsiString]: TALXMLNode read GetNodeByName; default;
property Nodes [const Index: integer]: TALXMLNode read GetNodeByIndex; default;
```

In `ALXmlDoc.hpp`:

```cpp
__property TALXMLNode * Nodes [const System :: AnsiString Name] = {read = GetNodeByName / *, default */};
__property TALXMLNode * Nodes [const int Index] = {read = GetNodeByIndex};
```

I get an error about duplication - how to fix it?

---

In `.pas` line 705

```pascal
property OnParseText: TAlXMLParseTextEvent read FonParseText Write FonParseText; // [added from TXMLDocument]
```

In `ALXmlDoc.hpp`:

```cpp
__property _di_TAlXMLParseTextEvent OnParseText = {read = FonParseText, write = FonParseText};
__interface TAlXMLParseTextEvent: public System :: IInterface
{
    virtual void __fastcall Invoke (System :: TObject * Sender, const System :: AnsiString Path, const System :: AnsiString Str) = 0;
};
     
private:
    _di_TAlXMLParseTextEvent FonParseText;
protected:
    void __fastcall DoParseText (const System :: AnsiString Path, const System :: AnsiString Str);
```

In my `Unit1.h`:

```cpp
void __fastcall OnParseText (System :: TObject * Sender, const System :: AnsiString Path, const System :: AnsiString Str);
```

In my `Unit1.cpp`:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1 :: OnParseText (System :: TObject * Sender, const System :: AnsiString Path, const System :: AnsiString Str)
{
    ShowMessage(Str); 
}
// ------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1 :: Button1Click (TObject * Sender)
{
    TALXMLDocument * aXMLDocument = new TALXMLDocument ("root");
    aXMLDocument-> OnParseText = OnParseText;
}
```

I get an error:

> [bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp (30): E2235 Member function must be called or its address taken

How to declare an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, array properties can't be overloaded solely on their index type. So you will have to rename one of the offending properties, there is no other option.  And then I would suggest you file a report with the library author asking to make the library be more friendly to C++ users.

---

In the Delphi code, `TAlXMLParseTextEvent` is a reference to an [anonymous method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi):

```pascal
TAlXMLParseTextEvent = reference to procedure (Sender: TObject; const Path, Str: AnsiString);
```

Which is why it gets translated to an `__interface` on the C++ side (because anonymous methods really are implemented behind the scenes using interfaces).  Delphi-style anonymous methods require extra handling in C++, as is documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[How to Handle Delphi Anonymous Methods in C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B)

> Under the cover, Delphi implements anonymous methods types (also known as method references) via an interface that implements an `Invoke(...)` method.
>
> So a method that takes a method reference parameter in Delphi is exposed to C++ as a method that takes an interface.

As such, your C++ code would need to do something more like this instead:

```cpp
struct TParseTextMethod
{
    void operator()(TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str)
    {
        ShowMessage(Str); 
    }
};
//------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TALXMLDocument *aXMLDocument = new TALXMLDocument("root");

    // the TMethodRef functor is defined in the documentation,
    // you can copy/paste it as-is into your code...
    typedef TMethodRef<TAlXMLParseTextEvent,
                     TParseTextMethod,
                     void,
                     TObject *Sender,
                     const AnsiString,
                     const AnsiString> MyMethRef;

    aXMLDocument->OnParseText = _di_TAlXMLParseTextEvent(new MyMethRef(TParseTextMethod()));
}
```

Or, you can streamline the functor usage a bit more by not using the `TMethodRef` wrapper (see [Inheritance and Interfaces](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Inheritance_and_Interfaces) and [Implementing Interfaces](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implementing_Interfaces:_Delphi_and_C%2B%2B)):

```cpp
class TParseTextMethod : public TCppInterfacedObject<TAlXMLParseTextEvent>
{
public:
    TParseTextMethod() {}
    INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN(TInterfacedObject);

    void __fastcall Invoke(TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str)
    {
        ShowMessage(Str); 
    }
};
//------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TALXMLDocument *aXMLDocument = new TALXMLDocument("root");

    aXMLDocument->OnParseText = _di_TAlXMLParseTextEvent(new TParseTextMethod());
}
```

Or, if you want to keep using your `OnParseText()` method as-is, then you will have to wrap it inside a functor, eg:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::OnParseText(TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str)
{
    ShowMessage(Str); 
}
//------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TAlXMLParseTextMethod)(TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str);

struct TParseTextMethod
{
    TAlXMLParseTextMethod Method;

    TParseTextMethod(TAlXMLParseTextMethod aMethod) : Method(aMethod) {}

    void operator()(TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str)
    {
        Method(Sender, Path, Str);
    }
};
//------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TALXMLDocument *aXMLDocument = new TALXMLDocument("root");

    typedef TMethodRef<TAlXMLParseTextEvent,
                     TParseTextMethod,
                     void,
                     TObject *Sender,
                     const AnsiString,
                     const AnsiString> MyMethRef;

    aXMLDocument->OnParseText = _di_TAlXMLParseTextEvent(new MyMethRef(TParseTextMethod(&OnParseText)));
}
```

Or:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::OnParseText(TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str)
{
    ShowMessage(Str); 
}
//------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TAlXMLParseTextMethod)(TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str);

class TParseTextMethod : public TCppInterfacedObject<TAlXMLParseTextEvent>
{
public:
    TAlXMLParseTextMethod Method;

    TParseTextMethod(TAlXMLParseTextMethod aMethod) : Method(aMethod) {}
    INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN(TInterfacedObject);

    void __fastcall Invoke(TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str)
    {
        Method(Sender, Path, Str);
    }
};
//------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TALXMLDocument *aXMLDocument = new TALXMLDocument("root");

    aXMLDocument->OnParseText = _di_TAlXMLParseTextEvent(new TParseTextMethod(&OnParseText));
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using one of the [Clang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers) then you can use a [C++ style lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of a functor:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TALXMLDocument *aXMLDocument = new TALXMLDocument("root");
    aXMLDocument->OnParseText = [](TObject*, const AnsiString, const AnsiString Str) {
        ShowMessage(Str);
    };
}
```

Or:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::OnParseText(TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str)
{
    ShowMessage(Str); 
}
//------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TALXMLDocument *aXMLDocument = new TALXMLDocument("root");
    aXMLDocument->OnParseText = [this](TObject *Sender, const AnsiString Path, const AnsiString Str) {
        OnParseText(Sender, Path, Str);
    };
}
```

Comment: **Remy Lebeau**
Here is my project https://drive.google.com/open?id=187NlB_vZDLhALEIY6kVIKGxMlWTjrwTh
Look, please, I rehearsed all your examples, except for the сlang, the message does not appear